# Test if socket is empty (was: Reading data from a raw socket)

Tags: r, sockets

At the start, I thought that the bad performance of my driver was caused by the way in which I read data from a socket.
This was the original function I used:

```
socket_char_reader = function(in_sock) {
  string_read <- raw(0)
  while((rd <- readBin(in_sock, what = "raw", n=1)) > 0) {
    string_read <- c(string_read, rd)
  }
  return(string_read %>% strip_CR_NUL() %>% rawToChar())
}
```

The results from 3 consecutive calls to this function give the expected result. It takes `0.004` seconds to read 29 bytes in total.

My second try reads the socket until it is empty. Another function splits the resulting raw array in 3 separate parts.

```
get_response = function() {
  in_sock   <- self$get_socket()
  BUF_SIZE <- 8
  chars_read <- raw(0)
  while (length(rd <- readBin(in_sock, what = "raw", n=BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
    chars_read <- c(chars_read, rd)
  }
  return(chars_read)
},
```

Reading from the socket now takes `2.049` seconds!

Can somebody explain to me what could be the cause for this difference (or what is the best method for reading the socket until it is empty)?

In the meantime I'll return to my original solution and continue looking for the cause of the bad performance.

Ben

---

I believe, I found the cause (but not the solution).

While debuging, I noticed that the delay is caused by the last call to readBin().
In socket_char_reader(), the stop-condition for the while-loop is based on the `value` of rd; if that value equals 0, the loop stops.
In get_response() the stop-condition is based on the `number of bytes in the buffer`. Before that number can be determined, readBin() first waits if any other bytes will be send to the socket.

The timeOut-period is set in the socketConnection() call.

```
private$conn <- socketConnection(host = "localhost", port, 
  open = "w+b", server = FALSE, blocking = TRUE, 
  encoding =   "UTF-8", timeout = 1)
```

Timeout has to be give a value > 0, otherwise it will take days before the loop stops.

Is it possible to check if there still are any bytes in the socket without actually reading?

Ben

Comment: What should it do if there are going to be more bytes but the server hasn't sent them yet? The server might send more bytes right after you decide there aren't any more bytes.

Comment: The transfer protocol is described here (https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Server_Protocol#Transfer_Protocol). It is clear how many blocks of bytes I can expect and what are the conventions for each block. So once I have read a chunk of bytes, it is easy to check if there aren't any more bytes.

Comment: How do you easily check if there aren't any more bytes?

Comment: Each chunk of bytes end with a 0x00 (embedded 0x00-bytes are prefixed with 0xFF so they can be distinguished from 0x00). The total stream end with either a 0x00 (indicating OK-status) or 0x01 (error). So according to the server protocol, the stream ends withe either 0x00-0x00 or 0x00-0x01. This information is used in the function that splits the total stream into the separate parts.

Comment: So you don't want to detect when there are no more bytes. You want to detect when there's a 0x00 which doesn't have a 0xFF prefix.

Comment: No. The problem is not how to test the values of the bytes. The problem is that before I can start testing, readbin first waits if more bytes will be sent. Maybe that changing the socketconnection to non-blocking mode will help. I'll experiment with that and let you know the results.